# Excel Formula how to sum when column (a) divide by column (b) is greater than 30

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is what I want to do. I want to sum column q, when q divide by w is greater than 30.  This is what I have:
=SUM(IF((Q:Q/W:W)>30,Q:Q,0))

It's returning a #value error.

Answer (score 1):

*Rather than simple formula you need an Array (CSE) formula:*

```
{=SUM(IF((SUM(Q:Q)/SUM(W:W))>30,Q:Q,0))}
```

**N.B.**

- Finish the formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Q1:Q3/W1:W3>30)*Q1:Q3)
```

[image]

For this formula, you ***CANNOT*** contain **blank** or **0** in *column **W***.

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach to the division test:

```
SUM(IFERROR((Q:Q)/(W:W),0))
```

There are two elements to this. The trivial one is that since you are doing whole columns, and there's no chance they are filled utterly to the brim, you would have divisions that error due to division by 0. The `IFERROR()` handles those, replacing them in the `SUM()` by 0's so as to have no effect.

The meat of it is how to write the division. Notice that each range is in `()` pairs. This is essential and matters in surprisingly many other situations:  formulas that do not work, even with standard ranging, simple `N16:N34` type ranges, suddenly will if you try putting a range or two in parentheses. Once you do this, the formula works.

I do not have access to Excel 2010 so I cannot test whether it works without `{CSE} entry` or not, but that's trivial to add if you enter the formula and it fails on pressing `Enter`.

Note that the `Rajesh S` formula would give you VERY VERY VERY wrong results. It's flaw is that it sums all of one column, then the other, and does a division with the results. Sounds fine, sort of, an "at first glance" sort of, but it seriously will not work.

Consider for instance, column Q has four values:  1, 2, 7, and 3. Column W has 4, 1, 3, and 2. That formula yields the two sums 13 and 10 with the division returning 1.3. A correct cell pair by cell pair division gives 1/4 ,2, 7/3, and 3/2. When you sum those, you get `6-1/12` ("6 and one-twelfth"). Very wrong. For your need, you must do all those divisions to find qualifying rows and sum the ones that qualified. So it just isn't right. At all.